# Different result featureCount() on QgsVectorLayer QGIS 1.8 vs QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I use the following code in a layer action:

```
<uri definition etc>    
sql = 'id = "[% "id" %]"';
uri.setSql(sql);
layername = 'TableName [% "id" %]';
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),layername,'spatialite');
<some code> if (vlayer.isValid() and vlayer.featureCount() > 0) else <some code>
```

The SQL-query gives as result 0 or more features. vlayer.featureCount() returns 0 or more as expected in QGIS 1.8, but always 359 in QGIS 2.0 (total features in Spatialite table with name TableName), so my code breaks in QGIS 2.0.
When the SQL-query has no result and I add vlayer to the interface and turn Show Feature Count on the layers panel shows two counts (?!) [359] and [0]. When the query returns 1 feature, these counts are [359] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex6FP.png). Open Attribute Table shows 0 and 1 record which is all fine. So the SQL-query seems to run fine, but featureCount holds the wrong number in my opinion.

[image: Show Feature Xount]

Any clue?

Comment: `sql = 'id = "[% "id" %]"';` that isn't valid SQL.  What provider are you using this against?

Comment: @NathanW I think the SQL runs fine, but something is wrong with feautureCount. I've added some extra info to my question.

Comment: I don't see how that query would run. The `"[% "id" %]"` is QGIS expression syntax, each provider uses it's own SQL style to query the layer.  If the query isn't running correctly it might be returning a bad result.